# How to unseal the gate in the Archylte Steppe?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

In the Archylte Steppe in ??? AF it says that it's sealed, but there's a way to unseal it in this time. It seems to hint beating the Gigantuars is doing something when I beat one, but I've only found two so far, and it's still sealed. If this is how you unseal it, where are all of them? Else, how do you break the seal?

Comment: How on earth do you beat them? Unrelated I know, but the giant silver one counted down from 6 to 0 then wiped my whole team in 1 hit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is indeed how you unseal the gate in the archlyte steppe.
In total there are 3 gigantuars statues.
You can encounter 2 of them only with specific weather conditions.

Here are the locations and the weather conditions:

- Stoneslump Wastelands - Any weather condition.
- Clearwater Marshes (northeast) - Sunny weather condition. (also
  requires a moogle hunt)
- Clearwater Marshes (central) - Rainy weather condition. (also
  requires a moogle hunt)

Comment: Nice... was look'n for this, Thnx

Answer (score 0):

You can get all three in sunny conditions, I just did. Two are close by each other in the clear water marshes, and the third is in the bunched up cacti.

Comment: No, the other answer's right. If you use Mog's ability on it to make it show up, it will still be there in other weather conditions though.

Answer (score 0):

I got all three to show up in sunny weather. I believe you need the fragment skill paradox scope to beat the monsters that show up afterwards - well at least if you dont want it to take forever.